# Error While installing rails, i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a project that requires Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.1.

I used RVM to install Ruby and it was installed fine. But, when I try to install Rails,

```
$ gem install rails --version '3.1.1'
```

It is throwing an error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    i18n requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: try adding gem 'i18n', '0.6.11' to your gemfile and bundle install again.

Comment: Also, I know you probably know this already but... you should really upgrade that ruby version!